# Merge the records for overlapping dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as below and want to merge the records for overlapping dates. MIN and MAX of start and end dates for overlapping records should be the Start and end date of merged record.

Before merge:

```
Item Code               Start_date       End_date
==============          ===========      ===========
111                     15-May-2004      20-Jun-2004
111                     22-May-2004      07-Jun-2004
111                     20-Jun-2004      13-Aug-2004
111                     27-May-2004      30-Aug-2004
111                     02-Sep-2004      23-Dec-2004
222                     21-May-2004      19-Aug-2004
```

Required output:

```
Item Code               Start_date       End_date
==============          ===========      ===========
111                     15-May-2004      30-Aug-2004
111                     02-Sep-2004      23-Dec-2004
222                     21-May-2004      19-Aug-2004
```

you can create sample data using

```
create table item(item_code  number, start_date date, end_date date);

insert into item values (111,to_date('15-May-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('20-Jun-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'));
insert into item values (111,to_date('22-May-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('07-Jun-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'));
insert into item values (111,to_date('20-Jun-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('13-Aug-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'));
insert into item values (111,to_date('27-May-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('30-Aug-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'));
insert into item values (111,to_date('02-Sep-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('23-Dec-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'));
insert into item values (222,to_date('21-May-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('19-Aug-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'));

commit;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variation of a gaps&islands problem. First calculate the maximum previous end date for each row. Then filter the rows where the current row's start date is greater than that max date, this is the start of a new group and the group's end date is found in the next row.

```
WITH max_dates AS
 (
   SELECT
      item_code  
     ,start_date 
     ,Max(end_date)  -- get the maximum prevous end_date
      Over (PARTITION BY item_code  
            ORDER BY start_date 
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS max_prev_date 
     ,Max(end_date)  -- get the maximum overall date (only needed for the last group)
      Over (PARTITION BY item_code) AS max_date 
   FROM   item
 )   
SELECT  
   item_code  
  ,start_date 
  ,Coalesce(Lead(max_prev_date)     -- next row got the end date for the current row
            Over (PARTITION BY item_code  
                  ORDER BY start_date) 
           ,max_date ) AS end_date  -- no next row for the last row --> overall maximum end_date

FROM max_dates
WHERE max_prev_date  < start_date -- maximum previous end date is less than current start date --> start of a new group
   OR max_prev_date  IS NULL      -- first row
```

Comment: instead of doing Coalesce(Lead(max_prev_date)     -- next row got the end date for the current row
            Over (PARTITION BY item_code  
                  ORDER BY start_date) 
           ,max_date ) AS end_date to get end_date , we can pull end_date in base query

Comment: @MayurRandive: No, you can't, the end date might not be the date from the next row in the base query.

Comment: ok, thanks .. trying to think why would it not work. i have put answer below, it is derived from your response.

Answer (score 3):

The code for this type of problem is rather tricky.  Here is one approach that works pretty well:

```
with item (item_code, start_date, end_date) as (
      select 111,to_date('15-05-2004','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('20-06-2004','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
      select 111,to_date('22-05-2004','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('07-06-2004','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
      select 111,to_date('20-06-2004','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('13-08-2004','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
      select 111,to_date('27-05-2004','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('30-08-2004','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
      select 111,to_date('02-09-2004','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('23-12-2004','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
      select 222,to_date('21-05-2004','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('19-08-2004','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
     ),
     id as (
      select item_code, start_date as dte, count(*) as inc
      from item
      group by item_code, start_date
      union all
      select item_code, end_date, - count(*) as inc
      from item
      group by item_code, end_date
     ),
     id2 as (
      select id.*, sum(inc) over (partition by item_code order by dte) as running_inc
      from id
     ),
     id3 as (
      select id2.*, sum(case when running_inc = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by item_code order by dte desc) as grp
      from id2
     )
select item_code, min(dte) as start_date, max(dte) as end_date
from id3
group by item_code, grp;
```

And a [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler) to validate it.

What is this doing?  Good question.  The idea in these problems is to define the adjacent groups.  This method does so by counting the number of "starts" and "ends" up to a given date.  When the value is 0, a group ends.

The specific steps are as follows:

(1) Break out all the dates onto separate rows along with an indicator of whether the date is a start date or end date.  This indicator is key to defining the ranges -- +1 to "enter" and "-1" to exit.

(2) Calculate the running total of the indicators.  The 0s in this total are the ends of overlapping ranges.

(3) Do a reverse cumulative sum of the 0s to identify the groups.

(4) Aggregate to get the final results.

You can look at each of the CTEs to see what is happening in the data.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can try this. It will give your desired output but as performance point of view the query might slow down, When there is a large number of data to be checked.

```
DECLARE @item Table(item_code  int, start_date date, end_date date);

insert into @item values (111,'15-May-2004','20-Jun-2004');
insert into @item values (111,'22-May-2004','07-Jun-2004');
insert into @item values (111,'20-Jun-2004','13-Aug-2004');
insert into @item values (111,'27-May-2004','30-Aug-2004');
insert into @item values (111,'02-Sep-2004','23-Dec-2004');
insert into @item values (222,'21-May-2004','19-Aug-2004');


SELECT * FROM @item WHERE item_code IN (SELECT item_code FROM @item GROUP BY item_code) AND 
(start_date IN (SELECT max(start_date) FROM @item GROUP BY item_code) or start_date In (SELECT min(start_date) FROM @item GROUP BY item_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

with help of above answers i am able to simplify this as below

```
WITH max_dates AS
 (
   SELECT
      item_code  
     ,start_date 
     ,end_date
     ,Max(end_date)  
      Over (PARTITION BY item_code  
            ORDER BY start_date 
            ) AS max_date 
   FROM   item
 )  ,
 max_dates1 as 
 (
 select max_dates.* , lag(max_date) over(partition by item_code order by 1) as MPD from max_dates
 )
 select ITEM_CODE,start_date,end_date from max_dates1  
 WHERE MPD  < start_date
   OR MPD  IS NULL
```

Comment: Well, this is not returning the correct result (not even for your example data). Btw, you can't `order by 1` in an Analytic Function, there's no `order by column number` it orders by the value 1, i.e. all rows got the same value and the order by kind of random

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for the detailed explanation.